# How to loop a particular code for each populated cell in a column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I am automating the search process and downloading the results .

My code runs for one row, i want to loop the same for each populated cell in `1st column` .I have tried the below code but is throws an error

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
        Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        Dim HTMLAs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
        Dim HTMLA As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        Dim Aone As Range
        Dim Bone As Range
        Dim Cone As Range
        Dim SearchButton As Object
        Dim Results As Variant
        For i = 1 To 3
        IE.Visible = False
        IE.navigate "https://www.twinword.com/api/text-similarity.php"



        Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Loop

        Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

        Set Aone = Range("Ai")
        Set Bone = Range("Bi")
        Set Cone = Range("Ci")


        Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("demoInput1")
        HTMLInput.Value = Aone.Value


        Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("demoInput2")
        HTMLInput.Value = Bone.Value


        Set SearchButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("demoButton")

    'click on the first (and presumably only) object in the collection

    SearchButton.Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")) '2sec
          Results = HTMLDoc.getElementById("demoBox").innerText
            Range("Ci").Value = Results

    Next i
    End Sub
```

Just want to run the desired loop for all the cells in `Column A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `Range` property the wrong way.

**Change:**

```
    Set Aone = Range("Ai")
    Set Bone = Range("Bi")
    Set Cone = Range("Ci")
```

**with:**

```
    Set Aone = Range("A" & i)
    Set Bone = Range("B" & i)
    Set Cone = Range("C" & i)
```

Similarly change the last one as well.